# The security of Hidden Field Equations - sentence

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography

I am reading this paper ["The security of Hidden Field Equations (HFE)"](http://www.minrank.org/hfesec.pdf)

and at the end of the page 3 the author wrote:

> The random oracle paradigm would be to ignore that the function
>   formulae exist.

I know what is the random oracle paradigm but sincerily I do not understand why the

"The random oracle paradigm would be to ignore that the function
 formulae exist."

Could you explain me please what that sentence means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random oracles are used in cryptographic proofs as a way to abstract away a complex function, making the analysis easier (ie "ignore the actual function, and model it as a random oracle instead").

In the paragraphs before the sentence you highlighted, they propose to measure the "complexity" of an equation / function by the degree of its multivariate polynomial representation over $GF(2)$.

In the context of the surrounding paragraphs, I would interpret that sentence to mean

> The random oracle paradigm abstracts away the complexity of the function, which renders our complexity metric useless.

Comment: it is my poor english? or there is help of the author to confuse everybody?

Comment: No, I agree with you that the sentence could have been better worded.